# SyncAdapter - detect when to synchronize server with the client (mobile)

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-syncadapter

I have a `form` inside my `mobileApp` to add a new `item`.
When there are `no internet connection`, and that an item is added to `sqlite localdb`, I want this data to be uploaded to the `server` (synced), once device is connected to the `internet`.

I have implemented a `SyncAdapter`, coupled with a simple `ContentProvider`, but I dont know how to detect that a `row` need to be `created/updated/deleted` on the server.

Do I need to add a `flag column` to the `table` (having values `created/updated/deleted/none`)
and if that's the case, is the `uploading` to the server done with just a call to `server api methods` or with `ContentResolver`.

My last question is where do I place this code? inside `performSync()` method? or I have to add a `receiver` which react when mobileapp is connected to internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `content provider` does notify `sync adapter` when a modification occured on `local db`.